# check existence of file in a directory based on multiple conditions

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

We receive csv files from our vendors and I wrote the below file check when the job runs at 10:00 am in the morning if the last received file was from previous day. Lately the file gets placed after midnight. Now we want to make sure if the last file received is either from current or previous day based on LastWriteTime. Check if the latest csv file LastWriteTime is from either the current day or previous day.

For instance, We received 05/26 csv file around 3:00 am 05/27 and 05/27 csv file around 11:30 pm (05/27) so when the job runs 05/28 at 10:00 am. The script should pick-up the csv file from 11:30 pm (05/27). Is there a better way of doing the file check.

```
#FileCheck

$File = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Test\" -Filter "*.csv" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

    if(($File.LastWriteTime.Date -ne [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).Date) -OR ($File.LastWriteTime.Date -ne [datetime]::Today.Date))
    {
            #Raise error
    }
```

Comment: since you only care to know if the timestamp is greater than or equal to one day ago ... just test for that. it will save you a 2nd calculation AND a 2nd comparison.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, Sure. Thanks very much.

Comment: you are quite welcome **gr... there really doesn't seem to be any other change that would be meaningful. my _personal_ preference would be to get the age-in-days of the file and see if it was in the range of `0..1`. that is the same test ... and no better, just a personal preference.